# Jedis Storage Confusion, Is this issue from Redis or Jedis?

Tags: redis, jedis

The following java code inserts a million integer pairs into redis.

```
 public class JedisInsertion { 
        public static byte[] fromInt(int v) { 
                return ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(v).array(); 
        } 
        public static void main(String args[]) { 
                Jedis j = new Jedis("localhost"); 
                for (int i = 0;i<1000*1000;i++){ 
                   j.set(fromInt(i),fromInt(i)); 
                } 
        } 
}
```

here is redis info output

```
... 
used_memory:89319664 
arch_bits:64 
...
```

89319664 implies ~ 89 bytes per key value pair.

I was expecting something around 8 MB instead (4 bytes for key + 4 bytes value).

I also compiled redis in 32 bit mode (still running the test on a 64 
bit machine).

The results for 32-bit version of redis:

used_memory: 68831664  => 68 bytes per key value pair.

Both results are several times higher than what I was expecting.

When I look at redis using CLI, I see a typical key would look like this: "\x00\x00\xc2\xff"

I appreciate your feedback

PS - I am using Redis 2.2.14 and Jedis 2.0 on a 64-bit machine

PSS - I also tried to store all the values in one hash as suggested by one of the comments, here is the code:

```
for (int i = 0;i<1000*1000;i++){
    j.hset("my-hash".getBytes(),fromInt(i),fromInt(i));
}
```

And here is the results:

```
used_memory_rss:84676608 (for 32bit build)
used_memory:105319712 (for 64bit build)
```

The results are even worse when I use a single hash.

Answer (score 1):

68 byes per key/value type are correct. Redis does not internally store things as a plain text file, otherwise it would not be able to lookup it in a fast way, to have different types of objects, and so forth. There is an associated overhead. There are more informations about that in the documentation at Redis.io.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that your key is a non-readable binary value is a decision made by Jedis, since Redis can use pretty much anything as a key.

Redis keys have expirations and other meta-data that takes up additional space. If you are concerned about space, consider storing all your values within a single Redis hash. There is significantly less overhead for key/value pairs within a hash than for standard key/value pairs.

http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization